# 403:The request is understood, message - SSL is required code - 92 but it has been refused Twitter Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. 
    This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits 
    (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following)
    W/System.err(1466): message - SSL is required
    code - 9
    entry corrupt or truncated

```
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or

http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10981ab8
0
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-10981ab8], statusCode=403, message=SSL is required, code=92, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)

twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
 twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1871)
 twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:241)
 br.com.dina.oauth.instagram.example.Facebook$2$1$1.onClick(Facebook.java:121)
 android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)

 android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)

android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update to the latest version of Twitter4j.  The old one didn't specify https - Twitter now requires that.

Comment: I am use twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar. This is latest version or not?

Comment: thanks for my question reply your ans. i am using  twitter4j-core » 3.0.5 solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem with Twitter4j 3.0.5 jar.